# When interviewers ask for a time slot for availability, is it common to ask why I'm unavailable in times I didn't list?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing

I had a phone interview and during the end of the interview, the interviewer asked what times I'd be available for an in person interview. Since he gave me a choice to choose, I said I prefer afternoon and evenings. He clarified this (mentioning they won't be there in the evenings) and said "why not the mornings?". My response was that I have to run errands in the mornings, but if he really needs it then sure I'll come in. He said "oh no I was just wondering why not the mornings".

I did mention that I'd be available 9-5 for the actual job.

It was for a student part time position at university.

I'm just wondering if it's common for interviewers to question the times I'm not available.

Comment: He was probably wanted to make sure if you are full time employed elsewhere or not.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Doesn't matter, I just thought it was very specific and felt I didn't need to provide a reason. If it's common I figured it should be something I need to get comfortable answering.

Comment: Sounds like a rude question to me. Don't know why he asked it, don't really care, it still sounds rude.

Comment: It just sounds like you caught them off guard.  Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never been asked that question in 30 years of interviewing.  I personally find it it be none of their business.  Having said that, I wouldn't be offended or annoyed by it and would answer it honestly.

There are several possibilities of why he would ask that:

1. Asking if you have a job already.
2. Wondering if you have commitments that you can't alter for the job.
3. He could be wondering if you aren't available mornings because of hangovers. You would be surprised at how many people would freely admit that they like to hang out in bars at night.
4. He could just be trying to get a general feel for your personality and making small talk.

I personally would suspect #1 or #4. Either way, don't sweat it.

Comment: I freely admit that I like to hang out in bars at night...

Comment: Yep, never been asked this either but I've also never said that I'd prefer afternoon and evening time slots for an interview so that's to be expected. Given what the OP mentioned and *especially* that this is a student position I'm not at all surprised that he would ask that follow-up question.

Comment: @djechlin unfortunately, there are many students who still haven't learned the art of "adulting yet" (or at least how to be a functioning alcoholic) so I could see that line of questioning being used to determine where the student's priorities lie.

Comment: While not asked this question specifically, I have been asked if I had suitable transportation!  Who knows, maybe the interviewer had a slew of people with car trouble that couldn't make the mornings or they have to drive in from a remote location.  Follow up questions are fairly common, even if some of them seem off the wall.

Answer (score 0):

I would have just responded with "any personal responsibilities I like to take care of in the mornings".
I've never been asked this question either from an interviewer in 40+ years of working but I wouldn't be overly concerned about it either.

Answer (score -1):

When he asked what time you're available you mentioned afternoons or evenings. To me, that is a strange response because jobs typically end between 9-5 so asking to be available in the evening for a interview sounds a bit out there.

So he was probably trying to figure you out without asking.